# AWS Cognito get User Group in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

So I've implemented Amazon Cognito login on an iOS app in Swift and it all works great. However I'm now trying to find out the groups that a logged in user belongs to. I can't seem to find a good way of doing this from within the app. The SDK doesn't seem to provide a way of doing so from what I can see. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Currently the groups are exposed in the ID token issued to the user.
It is populated in claim "cognito:groups".
More details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html

Comment: Is this for iOS SDK?

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in swift. I get an error when attempting to access members of token.claims